# Selecting date by month and year from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm making a calendar with events in Codeigniter, so I want do build a list of this events sorted by month and year.

In database, I have the list of events and I want to retrieve then by the field date, that uses the DATE datatype.

```
    if($year != null and $month != null)
    {
        $this->db->where('date', '?');
    }
    $events = $this->db->get('agenda')->result();
```

Basically i have a yyyy-mm to compare with a yyyy-mm-dd.

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Your question is not clear, sorry. What range of rows to you want to retrieve?  It seems you want to order them by year and month once you have retrieved them. Is that right?

Comment: I want to retrieve all events that are on the month and year that the user selected. But on the date field the date is in yyyy-mm-dd format. And I just have the yyyy-mm information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `$this->db->where()` makes a `AND field = value` try this.

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d')", $month);
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y')", $year );
```

The `DATE_FORMAT()` function is a MYSQL function for manipulating/formating dates so this should equate to

```
WHERE
     DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d') = '12'
 AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y') = '2014'
```

Or you could use

```
$this->db->where('MONTH(date)', $month);
$this->db->where('YEAR(date)', $year );
```

Comment: Notice that this correct solution defeats the use of an index to search the `date` column. and so may not perform as well as it could.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql your query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name >='2000-10-1'  //Y-m-d

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name >='2000-10-1' AND data_field_name <='2014-10-1'

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name >='2000-10-1'

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name BETWEEN '2000-10-1' AND '2014-10-1'
```

You can do this also

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE YEAR( data_field_name ) >= '2010' AND MONTH( data_field_name ) >='10' AND DAY( data_field_name ) >= '1'
```

etc....

for you use case I would do something like this

```
SELECT
    *, MONTH( date_field) as month
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    something = '1'
ORDER BY 
    month
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is as follows:

```
$monthstring = sprintf('%d-%d-01', $year, $month); /* make yyyy-mm-01 string */
$this->db->where ( "date >= '$monthstring'");
$this->db->where ( "date < '$monthstring' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
```

This is a good way to do this because it allows an index to be used to search the `date` column if one happens to be available.

It expands to this sort of MySQL where clause

```
 WHERE date >= '2014-07-01' AND date < '2014-07-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

That's exactly what you need for an index range scan.

Answer (score -1):

That query should solve your problem!

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name >='01/10/2000'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name between '01/01/2009' and '01/01/2010'; //FOR YEAR
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data_field_name between '01/01/2009' and '01/02/2009'; //FOR MONTH
```

Comment: Yeah, it should but i don't have the yyyy/mm/dd information. Just yyyy-mm.

Comment: But for having a entire Month you just ask to show from day 1 to the last day =). You can also you date() PHP function, to give you the today date, just like this: echo date('Y/m/d')

Comment: It's MYSQL.  Date strings are `yyyy-mm-dd`